# H2 unit test alias complaining about alias "AS[*]"

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, h2

I have the folowing code which runs fine for the application when it connects to mySql database. The issue is that unit tests use H2 which causes a syntax error at the word "AS" implying that aliases might not be supported here.

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO `ims`.`OrderEntries` (ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, ITEM_QUANTITY) VALUES (?, ?, ?) AS NEW_INSERTION ");
    builder.append("ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `ims`.`OrderEntries`.ITEM_QUANTITY = `ims`.`OrderEntries`.ITEM_QUANTITY + NEW_INSERTION.ITEM_QUANTITY");

    stmt = conn.prepareStatement(builder.toString(), 
                                 Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Is there a way to re-write the SQL statement such that it is H2 compatible?

```
INSERT INTO `ims`.`OrderEntries` (ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, ITEM_QUANTITY) VALUES (?, ?, ?) AS NEW_INSERTION 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `ims`.`OrderEntries`.ITEM_QUANTITY = `ims`.`OrderEntries`.ITEM_QUANTITY + NEW_INSERTION.ITEM_QUANTITY
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
INSERT INTO `ims`.`OrderEntries` (ORDER_ID, ITEM_ID, ITEM_QUANTITY) VALUES (?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `ims`.`OrderEntries`.ITEM_QUANTITY =
`ims`.`OrderEntries`.ITEM_QUANTITY + VALUES(ITEM_QUANTITY)
```